# redirect from the controller, depending on the role, to different views

Tags: php, laravel, roles, laravel-9

This is the error I have

[screenshot error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yU3Il.png)

Here I attach the code in my controller
$siniestro->update($request->all());

```
         function authenticated(Request $request, $user) {
        if ($user->role_id == 1) {
            return redirect('siniestros.index');
        } else  ($user->role_id == 2) {
            return redirect('siniestros.derivar');
        }
    };
```

Comment: You do have a syntax error, you need to use `elseif` to continue nested if blocks. You could always use a `switch` statement instead or `match` if you're using PHP 8^.

Comment: tnx buddy! work for me!